# Use a string of expressions in a method for python

Tags: parsing, python-2.7

For example, if I have the string:

```
"id=100 id2=200 id3=300 ..."
```

where the variable names, values, and number of expressions can be anything.

How can I then use that string in a method that is used like this:

```
method(id=100,id2=200,id3=300,...)
```

I get the string from a command line argument.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far that didn't work? Are you set on using that non-standard format instead of something argparse can read easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We parse them iteratively:

```
pairs = "id=100 id2=200 id3=300".split(' ')
res = {}
for p in pairs:
    k,v = p.rsplit('=', 1)
    res[k] = v

print res # prints {'id2': '200', 'id': '100', 'id3': '300'}
# now we can send the dictionary to the method
```

Comment: "The values can be anything" in the OP's question seems to imply they're not always integers.

Comment: @Wooble in the example he gave - he's sending ints to the method - if the values are not ints - it's pretty easy to modify my answer and have the values as strings. I'll add a comment.

Comment: The values can be integers or strings but it won't be too hard to code around that.

Comment: Can they be strings with embedded `=` and whitespace? The question's rather underspecified.

Comment: @Wooble if the keys/values contains whitespaces - it might not be possible to parse the string that way. In case the OP is running into such a corner-case, he/she should post the problematic example and then we'll be able to see if it can be handled with a more "sophisticated" regex.

Comment: The strings should be able to take in any characters including `=`. Keys will have no whitespace. Don't worry about any whitespace between the variable name, `=`, and the value

Comment: @user1102901 can the values also contain `=` (or just the keys) ? in case the answer is 'no' we can use `rsplit(p, 1)`. In case the answer is 'yes' then there's no way to parse it because there's no deterministic way to choose the right `=` as a separator. I updated the answer respectively.

Comment: Okay, I guess I will have to adjust it to not allow `=` in the value. Other than that, your code worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert it to a dictionary:

```
>>> s = "id=100 id2=200 id3=300"
>>> d = dict(a.split('=') for a in s.plit())
>>> print d
{'id2': '200', 'id': '100', 'id3': '300'}
```

And now use it in functions:

```
>>> method(**d)
```